# How to show ajax results in WooCommerce order tracking

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

In order tracking in WooCommerce, track results are displayed as a whole new page when submitting the tracking form. However, what I wanted to see are the results in AJAX.

Here is the form in woocommerce/templates/order/form-tracking.php:

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( $post->ID ) ); ?>" method="post" class="woocommerce-form woocommerce-form-track-order track_order">

    <p><?php esc_html_e( 'To track your order, please enter your Order ID and the email you used during checkout. You can find these in your receipt and confirmation email.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

    <p class="form-row form-row-first"><label for="orderid"><?php esc_html_e( 'Order ID', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label> <input class="input-text" type="text" name="orderid" id="orderid" value="<?php echo isset( $_REQUEST['orderid'] ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['orderid'] ) ) : ''; ?>" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Found in your order confirmation email.', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /></p><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
    <p class="form-row form-row-last"><label for="order_email"><?php esc_html_e( 'Billing email', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label> <input class="input-text" type="text" name="order_email" id="order_email" value="<?php echo isset( $_REQUEST['order_email'] ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['order_email'] ) ) : ''; ?>" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Email you used during checkout.', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /></p><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <p class="form-row"><button type="submit" class="button" name="track" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Track', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Track', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button></p>
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-order_tracking', 'woocommerce-order-tracking-nonce' ); ?>

</form>
```

I tried adding this in the same file right after the closing form tag and within the script tag:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('from_ajax', '1');// append this to your form.

 $('.track_order').submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
    $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
        data: formData, // get the form data
        type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
        url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
        success: function(response) { // on success..
            $('.track-results').html(response); // update the DIV
        }
    });
    return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
});

if(isset($_POST['from_ajax']){
     if($_POST['from_ajax'] == 1){
         // do not load header or footer , just load required view to display.
     }
}
```

I've found this jQuery from another question asked almost 5 years ago, but the jQuery doesn't seem to make any change, the order track results still show as whole new page. I don't know what else I should add or if anything is amiss. Should I add the jQuery in another file? Should I add more or make any more modifications in the jQuery?

Thank you all, I'm a total noob!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things are wrong. One tip is to check out any errors in the browser console first. There should be some in there.

**First possible problem:**

Returning false in the `submit()` handler could work to prevent the form from submitting, but only when there are no errors. A better way (also allowing you to keep seeing the browser console log easily) would be to use `event.preventDefault()`

```
$('.track_order').submit(function(event) { // <-- add event as argument here
    event.preventDefault(); // <-- better way to prevent form from submitting
    // Rest of your script code
}
```

**Second possible problem:**

`$` might not exist. In Wordpress, you should probably use `jQuery` in this code instead of the `$` shorthand (unless you define `$`). So first step would be to replace the `$` by jQuery inside of the `<script>` tags.

```
jQuery('.track_order').submit(function(event) { // <-- replace $ by jQuery
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery.ajax({ // // <-- replace $ by jQuery
        data: formData,
        type: jQuery(this).attr('method'), // <-- replace $ by jQuery
        url: jQuery(this).attr('action'), // <-- replace $ by jQuery
        success: function(response) {
            jQuery('.track-results').html(response); // <-- replace $ by jQuery
        }
    });
});
```

**Third possible problem:**

Make sure you actually have a HTML element with class 'track-results' somewhere so the data can be displayed after loading through AJAX.

```
<div class="track-results"></div>
```

**Fourth possible problem:**

`FormData` does not work together with jQuery's `ajax()` method like that, because jQuery wants to stringify that, but it shouldn't do that when the data is supplied as a `FormData` object.

Two possible solutions:

Solution 1 - Set `processData` and `contentType` to `false` when doing the `ajax()` request

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        // All the other fields
    });
```

OR solution 2 - Simply use a plain JavaScript object instead of `FormData`

```
var formData = {
    'from_ajax': '1'
}
```

instead of

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('from_ajax', '1');
```

**Fifth possible problem:**

This last part of your script is PHP and should not be in the JS script tags:

```
if(isset($_POST['from_ajax']){
     if($_POST['from_ajax'] == 1){
         // do not load header or footer , just load required view to display.
     }
}
```

Instead, it should be in the PHP file mentioned in the `action` attribute of the form.

**Some extra information:**

Don't just go and edit core Wordpress files either. You can probably do what you need to do using an AJAX action in Wordpress. Although the documentation is not very beginner friendly in my opinion, here it is: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/

This older entry in the WP Codex might actually explain the basics in a simpler way: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

**Full example:**

I'm loading WP core here by including wp/wp-load.php so I can use the WP functions, and I have set the `action` attribute to be the test file itself. Just so I can give you a complete example contained in one file.

```
<?php
include 'wp/wp-load.php';
if (isset($_POST['from_ajax']) && $_POST['from_ajax'] == 1) {
    die('tada! here is the example response ...');
}
?>

<form action="test.php" method="post" class="woocommerce-form woocommerce-form-track-order track_order">

    <p><?php esc_html_e( 'To track your order, please enter your Order ID and the email you used during checkout. You can find these in your receipt and confirmation email.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

    <p class="form-row form-row-first"><label for="orderid"><?php esc_html_e( 'Order ID', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label> <input class="input-text" type="text" name="orderid" id="orderid" value="<?php echo isset( $_REQUEST['orderid'] ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['orderid'] ) ) : ''; ?>" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Found in your order confirmation email.', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /></p><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
    <p class="form-row form-row-last"><label for="order_email"><?php esc_html_e( 'Billing email', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label> <input class="input-text" type="text" name="order_email" id="order_email" value="<?php echo isset( $_REQUEST['order_email'] ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['order_email'] ) ) : ''; ?>" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Email you used during checkout.', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /></p><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <p class="form-row"><button type="submit" class="button" name="track" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Track', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Track', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button></p>
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-order_tracking', 'woocommerce-order-tracking-nonce' ); ?>

</form>

<div class="track-results">result will be shown here</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('from_ajax', '1');// append this to your form.

jQuery('.track_order').submit(function(event) { // catch the form's submit event
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent form submit
    jQuery.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
        data: formData, // get the form data
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
        url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
        success: function(response) { // on success..
            $('.track-results').html(response); // update the DIV
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I hope this helps you out!

Comment: Here's what I did: I've put the WC shortcode for the order tracking form in a div, and named the div class="track-results". Now, I tried your full example, but nothing happened when I click the button. So I tried replacing the action="test.php" with the original. The whole page reloaded again, but this time it didn't reload to the top of the page but to the div where it left off. However, the loaded results where literally the whole page of the current page inside the div, with the "tada! here is the example response ..."  on the order tracking section.

Comment: Should I have created a test.php file with the PHP script inside? Also, should I replace the "tada! here is the example response ..." with "<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( $post->ID ) ); ?>" so that it would contain the order result?

Comment: Here's the div I'm working on (with the new scripts) if you need a look: http://nikkaellacorrea.com/iteration3/#quick-tracking

Comment: This is an example. And when using WP you're better off handling AJAX like this: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/ or https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( $post->ID ) ); ?>" method="post" class="woocommerce-form woocommerce-form-track-order track_order">

    <p><?php esc_html_e( 'To track your order, please enter your Order ID and the email you used during checkout. You can find these in your receipt and confirmation email.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

    <p class="form-row form-row-first"><label for="orderid"><?php esc_html_e( 'Order ID', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label> <input class="input-text" type="text" name="orderid" id="orderid" value="<?php echo isset( $_REQUEST['orderid'] ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['orderid'] ) ) : ''; ?>" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Found in your order confirmation email.', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /></p><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
    <p class="form-row form-row-last"><label for="order_email"><?php esc_html_e( 'Billing email', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label> <input class="input-text" type="text" name="order_email" id="order_email" value="<?php echo isset( $_REQUEST['order_email'] ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['order_email'] ) ) : ''; ?>" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Email you used during checkout.', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /></p><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <p class="form-row"><button type="submit" class="button" name="track" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Track', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Track', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button></p>
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-order_tracking', 'woocommerce-order-tracking-nonce' ); ?>

</form>

<script>
jQuery('.track_order').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    jQuery.ajax({
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: jQuery(this).attr('method'),
        url: 'tracking.php',
        success: function(response) {
            var orderInfo = jQuery(response).find('.woocommerce').html();
            jQuery('.track_order').html(orderInfo); // update the DIV
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

and this is the tracking.php

```
$notes = $order->get_customer_order_notes();
?>

<p class="order-info">
    <?php
    echo wp_kses_post(
        apply_filters(
            'woocommerce_order_tracking_status',
            sprintf(
                /* translators: 1: order number 2: order date 3: order status */
                __( 'Order #%1$s was placed on %2$s and is currently %3$s.', 'woocommerce' ),
                '<mark class="order-number">' . $order->get_order_number() . '</mark>',
                '<mark class="order-date">' . wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ) . '</mark>',
                '<mark class="order-status">' . wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ) . '</mark>'
            )
        )
    );
    ?>
</p>

<?php if ( $notes ) : ?>
    <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Order updates', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
    <ol class="commentlist notes">
        <?php foreach ( $notes as $note ) : ?>
        <li class="comment note">
            <div class="comment_container">
                <div class="comment-text">
                    <p class="meta"><?php echo date_i18n( esc_html__( 'l jS \o\f F Y, h:ia', 'woocommerce' ), strtotime( $note->comment_date ) ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?></p>
                    <div class="description">
                        <?php echo wpautop( wptexturize( $note->comment_content ) ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_view_order', $order->get_id() ); ?>
```

Comment: Hi, while your answer may address the question, you can improve it by adding explanations, citations, or related links to documentation.  Your answer will become much more useful for the whole Community